# GDB a PIE that moved itself

Tags: gdb, kernel

I'm writing a kernel which is compiled as a PIE. After boot the kernel maps itself into 64-bit high mem, specifically the NULL page moves to `0x1FFFF << 0x2F`, and then jumps there however in doing so GDB loses track of the code that accompanies the assembly. I lose the ability to set breakpoints(doing so triggers my breakpoint ISR instead of GDB) and am forced to step one instruction at a time through my C with nothing but assembly showing in GDB. Is there some way I can change the base address of my kernel executable in GDB at runtime. I'm connecting to QEMU's GDB server for debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there some way I can change the base address of my kernel executable in GDB at runtime

This should work:

```
(gdb) add-symbol-file kernel_exe 0x....  # where 0x... is the relocated address of .text
```

Comment: Hmmm, `add-symbol-file Debug/NekOS $0xFFFF800000100000` gives me `add symbol table from file "Debug/NekOS" at Value can't be converted to integer.` I assume GDB isn't terribly happy with the big 64-bit addr I gave it. I'll update my question to specify I mean 64-bit high mem not 32-bit high mem.

Comment: Dollar sign (`$`) is not a part of the command specification.

Comment: @Scoopta by `$relocated_address` I mean: substitute relocated address here. In your case, the command should be something like `add-symbol-file Debug/NekOS 0xFFFF8000001004010` -- note: it should be the location of `.text`, after the file header (if any).

Comment: Oh, GAS likes absolute values to have `$` and I had to replace `kernel_exe` in your example too so I figured I was supposed to leave it. This works great though, I do have to run `symbol-file` first to clear the existing symbols or else the lowmem symbols get priority and GDB gets pretty angry when trying to do anything useful but after that everything is fine so thanks!